# How to rename indexes generated by group by function?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a weekly mean of data for every year. So I am using `groupby` for week and year as in the below code:

```
hdfc.groupby([hdfc.Date.dt.year,hdfc.Date.dt.week]).mean()
```

[image]

How can I make week and year as the columns of the data? reset_index() is giving me an error "cannot insert Date, already exists" since both the columns have the name Date which is generated by groupby function.

Comment: Can you post sample data in text form?

Comment: ``hdfc.groupby([hdfc.Date.dt.year, hdfc.Date.dt.week]).mean().reset_index(drop = True)`` ?

Comment: @Sushanth `drop=True` will drop both year & week. Don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below given piece of code will output your desired result:

```
df.rename_axis(index=['Year', 'Week']).reset_index()
```